# Execute navigation programmatically

Tags: flutter, async-await, navigator, flutter-deep-link

I try to implement a deep linking logic in my Flutter app. For navigation to my destination and to be sure to have the correct stack I need sometimes to choose the right tab on my `BottomNavigationBar`, then animate to the correct tab of my `TabBar` with `TabController`, scroll to the correct position in my `ListView` and push then to a for example `DetailsScreen` of an item in the `ListView`.
But in case of the current state of my current `Tab` on `BottomNavigationBar` already opened a `DetailsScreen` I first need to pop the current Stack and then pushing to for example the details of another item in the list. Using a simple:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(TabNavigatorRoutes.details, arguments: item);
```

has the result the pushNamed never executed or simply poped immediately after been pushed because, I assume, the `pop()` still running in the same time so they kill each other.

I fixed this with:

```
await Navigator.maybePop(context);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(TabNavigatorRoutes.details, arguments: item);
```

which pops if possible and waits with executing the `pushNamed`, so fine that works.

**Problem, I also have deeper screens and need to execute for example `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);` to be sure I popped an existing stack before execute another deep link. Same problem here, a following `pushNamed` will not execute.
Differenz `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);` is a void function so I cannot use await here.**

I asked ChatGPT about the problem and got the following solution, I should use:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
await Future.delayed(Duration.zero); // Wait for microtask queue to clear
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(TabNavigatorRoutes.details, arguments: item);
```

which works yes, but It feels like a really dirty solution. Anyone else had this problem and founds a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by calling by using some basics:

```
while (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
   await Navigator.maybePop(context);
}
Navigator.pushNamed(context, TabNavigatorRoutes.details, arguments: item);
```

Maybe someone could tell if this could have side effects or could cause other problems? I think the solution is not ideal but better than `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);` I'm open for proposals!